# Starting my Node.js + Mongo API with Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I know it's maybe a beginner question, but I looked over it everywhere and I still having trouble with it.

I have a Node API that I run locally. The only thing I need to do is run in terminal:

```
$ mongod
```

and then

```
$ node src/loader.js
```

So, I upload my code to Heroku and added to my package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node src/loader.js"
    }
```

But when I run '$ heroku ps' it says that my process crashed. Whats the difference between my local build and the Heroku build?

Adding my Heroku logs --tail.

```
2018-02-05T19:19:17.648257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-05T19:19:17.648257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-05T19:19:17.732544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered the problem. Heroku dynamically assigns your app a port, so you can't set the port to a fixed number, and in my code I assigned to port: '3000'.

So you need to change to

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a look over the heroku logs from terminal 'heroku logs --tail', and if you need more detail you can go to the app in heroku and in the upper right view the logs in the heroku platform.

If you can post some of the logs it will be helpful in telling what's going wrong if you can't derive it from there on your review.

Comment: I says Error R10. That seens to be a Timeout